# How can I do this in SQL in a Single Statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following MySQL table:

```
+---------+------------+------+--------+------+---------+------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Version | Yr_Varient | FY   | Period | CoA  | Company | Item       | Mvt   | Ptnr_Co | Investee | GC         | LC         |
+---------+------------+------+--------+------+---------+------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 23      | 1110105000 | 60200 |         |          | 450000     | 450000     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 23      | 2110300000 | 60200 |         |          | -520000    | -520000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 23      | 1220221600 |       |         |          | 78080      | 78080      |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 23      | 2130323000 |       |         |          | 50000      | 50000      |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 23      | 2130322000 |       |         |          | -58080     | -58080     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 23      | 3100505000 |       |         |          | -275000    | -275000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 23      | 3200652500 |       |         |          | 216920     | 216920     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 23      | 3900000000 |       |         |          | 58080      | 58080      |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 26      | 1110105000 | 60200 |         |          | 376000     | 376000     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 26      | 2110300000 | 60200 |         |          | -545000    | -545000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 26      | 1220221600 |       |         |          | 452250     | 452250     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 26      | 2130323000 |       |         |          | -165000    | -165000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 26      | 2130322000 |       |         |          | -118250    | -118250    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 26      | 3100505000 |       |         |          | -937750    | -937750    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 26      | 3200652500 |       |         |          | 819500     | 819500     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 26      | 3900000000 |       |         |          | 118250     | 118250     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 37      | 1110105000 | 60200 |         |          | 777000     | 777000     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 37      | 2110308000 | 60200 | 43      |          | -255000    | -255000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 37      | 2130321500 |       |         |          | 180000     | 180000     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 37      | 2130322000 |       |         |          | -77000     | -77000     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 37      | 2310407001 |       | 1       |          | -625000    | -625000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 37      | 3100505000 |       |         |          | -2502500   | -2502500   |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 37      | 3200652500 |       |         |          | 2425500    | 2425500    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 37      | 3900000000 |       |         |          | 77000      | 77000      |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 1110105000 | 60200 |         |          | 2600000    | 2600000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 1140161000 | 60200 |         | 23       | 430000     | 430000     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 1140161000 | 60200 |         | 26       | 505556     | 505556     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 1140160000 | 60200 | 37      |          | 255000     | 255000     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 1160163000 | 60200 | 99999   | 48       | 49428895   | 49428895   |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 1160163000 | 60200 | 99999   | 49       | 188260175  | 188260175  |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 2310405500 |       |         |          | -237689070 | -237689070 |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 2110300000 | 60200 |         |          | -1000      | -1000      |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 2110300500 | 60200 |         |          | -3999000   | -3999000   |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 1220221600 |       |         |          | 1571112    | 1571112    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 2130321500 |       |         |          | -805556    | -805556    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 2130322000 |       |         |          | -556112    | -556112    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 3100505000 |       |         |          | -836000    | -836000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 3200652500 |       |         |          | 781000     | 781000     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 3300715700 |       | 99999   | 32       | -440000    | -440000    |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 3300715700 |       | 99999   | 26       | -61112     | -61112     |
| 201     | 1          | 2010 | 1      | 11   | 43      | 3900000000 |       |         |          | 556112     | 556112     |
+---------+------------+------+--------+------+---------+------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I need to take all rows with Mvt = 60200 and multiply every GC and LC record in that row by 1.1 and add a new row containing the changes back into the same table with FY set to 2011.

How can I do all this in 1 statement?
Is it even possible to do all this in 1 statement (I know very little about SQL)?
Can this be done in standard SQL as the database will be ported to another Database Server?
I don't know which server it will be.

Comment: Do you need to replace the existing rows, or to add new rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In standard SQL (there may be better ways in vendor-specific implementations but I tend to prefer standard stuff where possible):

```
insert into mytable (
    Version, Yr_Varient, Period, CoA, Company, Item, Mvt, Ptnr_Co, Investee,
    FY, GC, LC
) select
    Version, Yr_Varient, Period, CoA, Company, Item, Mvt, Ptnr_Co, Investee,
    2011, GC*1.1, LC*1.1
    from mytable
    where Mvt = 60200
    -- and FY = 2010
```

You may also want to limit your select statement a little more depending on the results of your testing, such as uncommenting the `and FY = 2010` line above to stop copying all your 2009 and 2008 data as well, if any. I asume you only wanted to carry forward the previous year's stuff with a 10% increase on `GC` and `LC`.

The way this works is to run the `select` which gives modified data for `FY`, `GC` and `LC` as per your request, and pump all those rows back into the `insert`.

Comment: On some DBMS, adding "and FY = 2010" is an absolute requirement. otherwise the statement would cause an endless loop of inserts (until the disk gets full or some other limit of table size reached).

Answer (score 0):

```
  insert into mytable (
    Version,Yr_Varient,FY,Period,CoA,Company,Item,Mvt,Ptnr_Co,Investee,GC,LC)
    SELECT Version ,Yr_Varient,"2011" as FY, Period, CoA, Company , Item , Mvt ,Ptnr_Co ,   Investee , GC*1.1 as GC, LC*1.1 as LC FROM <table Name> 
WHERE Mvt = 60200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO _table_ 
    (Version, 
    Yr_Varient, 
    FY, 
    Period, 
    CoA, 
    Company, 
    Item, 
    Mvt, 
    Ptnr_Co,
    Investee,
    GC, 
    LC)
SELECT
    Version,
    Yr_Varient,
    2011,
    Period,
    CoA,
    Company,
    Item,
    Mvt,
    Ptnr_Co,
    Investee,
    GC * 1.1,
    LC * 1.1
FROM
    _table_
WHERE
    Mvt = 60200
    AND FY <> 2011
```

This statement should work in any SQL-Database.

Edit: Too slow